# Long tap recognizer in Sprite Kit with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, long-integer, gesture

Hello I'm planning a game and an essential part of the game is to move left and right by pressing the right side of the screen or the left side.

But how can I detect a long press?

Many Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not called long tap. A tap can't be long. It is called UILongPressGestureRecognizer. You can take a look at the documents [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something while the user is holding down on the screen, you could use the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods to detect the hold.

```
var touching = false 

func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

touching = true


}

func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

touching = false

}
```